# mgo with aggregation and grouping

Tags: go, aggregation, mgo

I am trying to perform a query using golang mgo 
to effectively get distinct values from a join, I understand that this might not be the best paradigm to work with in Mongo.

Something like this:

```
pipe := []bson.M{

    {
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id":  bson.M{"user": "$user"},

        },
    },

    {
        "$match": bson.M{
            "_id":  bson.M{"$exists": 1},
            "user": bson.M{"$exists": 1},
            "date_updated": bson.M{
                "$gt": durationDays,
            },
        },

    },

    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "users",
            "localField":   "user",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "user_details",
        },
    },
    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "organizations",
            "localField":   "organization",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "organization_details",
        },
    },

}

err := d.Pipe(pipe).All(&result)
```

If I comment out the `$group` section, the query returns the join as expected.

If I run as is, I get `NULL`

If I move the `$group` to the bottom of the pipe I get an array response with Null values

Is it possible to do do an aggregation with a `$group` (with the goal of simulating `DISTINCT`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting NULL is because your `$match` filter is filtering out all of documents after the `$group` phase.

After your first stage of `$group` the documents are only as below example:

```
  {"_id": { "user": "foo"}},
  {"_id": { "user": "bar"}},
  {"_id": { "user": "baz"}}
```

They no longer contains the other fields i.e. `user`, `date_updated` and `organization`. If you would like to keep their values, you can utilise [Group Accumulator Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator). Depending on your use case you may also benefit from using [Aggregation Expression Variables](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/)

As an example using [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/), let's use [$first operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) which basically pick the first occurrence. This may make sense for `organization` but not for `date_updated`. Please choose a more appropriate accumulator operator.

```
{"$group": { 
          "_id":"$user", 
          "date_updated": {"$first":"$date_updated"}, 
          "organization": {"$first":"$organization"}
         }
}
```

Note that the above also replaces `{"_id":{"user":"$user"}}` with simpler `{"_id":"$user"}`.

Next we'll add [$project stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to rename our result of `_id` field from the group operation back to `user`. Also carry along the other fields without modifications.

```
{"$project": {
              "user": "$_id", 
              "date_updated": 1, 
              "organization": 1
             }
 }
```

Your [$match stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) can be simplified, by just listing the `date_updated` filter. First we can remove `_id` as it's no longer relevant up to this point in the pipeline, and also if you would like to make sure that you only process documents with `user` value you should placed `$match` before the `$group`. See [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) for more.

So, all of those combined will look something as below:

```
[
 {"$group":{ 
             "_id": "$user", 
             "date_updated": { "$first": "$date_updated"}, 
             "organization": { $first: "$organization"} 
           }
 },
 {"$project":{ 
               "user": "$_id", 
               "date_updated": 1, 
               "organization": 1
             }
 }, 
 {"$match":{
          "date_updated": {"$gt": durationDays } }
 }, 
 {"$lookup":{
             "from": "users", 
             "localField": "user", 
             "foreignField": "_id", 
             "as": "user_details"
            }
 }, 
 {"$lookup":{
            "from": "organizations", 
            "localField": "organization", 
            "foreignField": "_id", 
            "as": "organization_details"
            }
 }
]
```

(I know you're aware of it) Lastly, based on the database schema above with `users` and `organizations` collections, depending on your application use case you may re-consider embedding some values. You may find [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) useful.

Comment: thanks for such a comprehensive answer and explanation !